# Como integrar de forma prática e eficiente o Travis-ci com Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

Estou criando alguns Dockerfile + arquivos de configuração para minhas imagens, atualmente realizo o push para o GitHub, posteriormente o Travis-ci pega os arquivos e gera uma build, terminando faz o push para o Docker Hub.

Nessa abordagem tenho que inserir usuário e senha do Docker Hub lá nas definições do Travis-ci, não que isso seja exatamente um problema, porém, é incomodo. Alguma abordagem mais eficiente e prática?

Qual seria o fluxo mais adequado para esse processo?

Atualmente faço o deploy no Docker Hub via Travis-ci: https://github.com/docker-sources/php-apache-nodejs/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: No gitlab-ci, eu posso definir algumas variáveis secretas que serão usadas com o fim de serem consumidas no yml que gerencia o build. Essas variáveis são enxertadas como variáveis de ambiente e as uso normalmente. Como o gitlab-ci veio para ser o concorrente do travis-ci, creio que deva existir um mecanismo análogo

Comment: Dei uma olhada rápida, esse recurso é pago? No caso do Travis-ci não estou tendo custo pois o projeto é open source, com isso a ferramenta acabar não cobrando nada por sua utilização.

Comment: A intenção era fazer um paralelo com o travis-ci, não sugerir. Mas no meu entendimento é disponibilizado gratuita e ilimitadamente para projetos públicos open-source. É tipo o travis-ci do gitlab